# Android send json data to car's head unit

Tags: android, json, networking

I am working on a case that I haven't had any experience before. I have our navigation application installed on a tablet and a `head unit` to send navigation data. The problem is that I don't know how to exactly establish a connection between a `tablet` and a `head unit`. The case is simply to send a `JSON` data which is consist of a particular route body, from an Android tablet to the head unit using a POST method. However, I don't have any ideas about what method is it. I just found out `Wifi-Direct P2P` approach but I don't think it fits my case. Has anybody experienced such a case before? Your help is really appreciated! Thanks again!

Comment: This _probably_ depends on the head unit.

Comment: @RyanM yes you are correct why do you know the main idea behind it? How can I send JSON data to a head unit? As far as I see the head unit is based on Android. Thanks!